# Spring Data update mongodb Document with DBRF lazy attribute

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb, lazy-loading

I want to update a MongoDB document containing a dbrf lazy attribute using spring data.
First of all, I load the existing document, I change the attributes I want and after that, I call @Repository save method, but when I check the document in MongoDB the dbrf lazy attribute is null.

I tried to load the attribute before by calling getAttribute, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Someone could help me?
Thanks

I have the Collection below:

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "calendriers")
public class CalendrierEntity {

    @Id
    @AutoGenerate(SequanceKey.CALENDRIER)
    private Long id;

    @NotNul 
    private String label;

    @NotNull
    private HorairesEntity horairesEntity;

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    @CascadeSave
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private List<AbsenceEntity> absenceEntities;
}
```

and the repository bellow :

```
@Repository
public interface AbsenceRepository extends MongoRepository<CalendrierEntity, Long> {

    AbsenceEntity findById(Long enfantId, LocalDate localDate);
}
```

I have calendrier document with Id 1L and want to update his label.
The calendrier document have allready a list of Absences.

this my code to update the label.

```
@Transactional
public void updateLabelCalendrier(Long id, String label){
CalendrierEntity calendrier  = calenderRepository.findById(1L);
calendrier.setLabel(label);
calenderRepository.save(calendrier);
}
```

but when i check data in mongodb, i have the new label but my list of absences became null.

Comment: What have you tried? and how your collection records look like, please post here including what query have you run?

Comment: can you share your sample document and code you have approached as of now?

Comment: @krishnaPrasad  i added my code

Comment: @Oliver see my code below

Comment: @G.Issam Which version of `spring-data-mongodb` are you using?

Comment: @G.Issam What are the values of `absenceEntities` in the collection `calendriers`? Is it a list of `ObjectId` of the collection `AbsenceEntity`?

Comment: `@CascadeSave` is no SpringData provided annotation. Do you use some custom code to evaluate it